# How to exit Protractor test from Spec on specific condition?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, exit, e2e-testing

I have a suite which includes multiple specs. Each spec uses code on some libraries that return a rejected promise upon failure.

I can easily `catch` those rejected promises inside my spec. What I'm wondering about is that if I can make Protractor exit the whole suite inside that `catch` function, because the next specs inside the same suite are dependent on the success of the previous specs.

Pretend I have a suite called `testEverything` which has these specs `openApp`,`signIn`,`checkUser`,`logout`. If `openApp` fails, all next specs will fail due to dependency.

Consider this code for `openApp`:

```
var myLib = require('./myLib.js');

describe('App', function() {

  it('should get opened', function(done) {

    myLib.openApp()
    .then(function() {

      console.log('Successfully opened app');

    })
    .catch(function(error) {

      console.log('Failed opening app');

      if ( error.critical ) {
        // Prevent next specs from running or simply quit test
      }

    })
    .finally(function() {

      done();

    });

  });

});
```

How would I exit the whole test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to come up with a workaround. Now the actual code that I used is way more complex, but the idea is the same.

I added a global variable inside protractor's config file called `bail`. Consider the following code at the top of config file:

```
(function () {

  global.bail = false;

})();

exports.config: { ...
```

The above code uses an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which defines `bail` variable on protractor's `global` object (which would be available throughout the whole test).

I also have written asynchronous wrappers for the Jasmine matchers I need, which would execute an `expect` expression followed by a comparison, and return a promise (using `Q` module). Example:

```
var q = require('q');

function check(actual) {

    return {

      sameAs: function(expected) {

          var deferred = q.defer();
          var expectation = {};

          expect(actual).toBe(expected);

          expectation.result = (actual === expected);

          if ( expectation.result ) {

              deferred.resolve(expectation);
          }
          else {
              deferred.reject(expectation);
          }

          return deferred.promise;

      }

    };

}

module.exports = check;
```

Then at the end of each spec, I set the `bail` value based on the spec's progress, which would be determined by the promise of those asynchronous matchers. Consider the following as first spec:

```
var check = require('myAsyncWrappers'); // Whatever the path is

describe('Test', function() {

    it('should bail on next spec if expectation fails', function(done) {

        var myValue = 123;

        check(myValue).sameAs('123')
        .then(function(expectation) {

            console.log('Expectation was met'); // Won't happen

        })
        .catch(function(expectation) {

            console.log('Expectation was not met'); // Will happen

            bail = true; // The global variable

        })
        .finally(function() {

            done();

        });

    });

});
```

Finally, on the beginning of next specs, I check for `bail` and return if necessary:

```
describe('Test', function() {

    it('should be skipped due to bail being true', function(done) {

        if ( bail ) {

            console.log('Skipping spec due to previous failure');

            done();

            return;

        }

        // The rest of spec

    });

});
```

Now I want to mention that there's one module out there called `protractor-fail-fast` which bails on the whole test whenever an expectation fails.

But in my case, I needed to set that `bail` global variable depending on which type of expectation has been failed. I ended up writing a library (really small) that distinguishes failures as critical and non-critical and then using that, specs would be stopped only if a critical failure has occurred.

Comment: It's so sad that it had to come to this... I think I'll just let my dependent tasks fail, because I don't feel like adding that much boilerplate code. I have the exact same problem and I'm surprised there is no native way of doing this.

Comment: @Joffrey I understand if the code is too long for it's purpose. This should be a built-in functionality of Protractor/Jasmine since it's not that complicated. Maybe we should add an issue in their Github repo?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for `npm` called `protractor-fail-fast`.  Install the module `npm install protractor-fail-fast`.  Here's an example from their site where you would place this code into your conf file:

```
var failFast = require('protractor-fail-fast');

exports.config = {
  plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-fail-fast'
  }],

  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
  },

  afterLaunch: function() {
    failFast.clean(); // Cleans up the "fail file" (see below) 
  }  
}
```

Their url is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-fail-fast).

Comment: I'm aware of that, the thing is that I don't want my test to bail on the first failed expectation, but manually when I decide if the error is critical (failed login, failed signup, etc.) or not (wrong user name displayed).

Comment: Your script is going to do what you tell it to do, it cannot think on its own.  The only way for you to manually stop the test when you deem it appropriate to do so, is by pressing the `Control + C` keys.  Your question asked how to stop the test if a step failed, which is what the module I answered with can do.  Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly.

Comment: "What I'm wondering about is that if I can make Protractor **exit the whole suite inside that catch function**...", I have async wrappers for expect statements which will reject the promise chain when an expectation fails. As I specifically said, I want to quit test manually when I catch those rejected promises (in case the error code that those promises return is reporting a critical error only). That's the real question.